# mySQL how to unpivot dynamic columns

Tags: mysql, sql, date, union, unpivot

I have the following table below:

Table name: STAT

```
Region   M07  M08 M09 
---------------------
P1       0    1   0    
P2       0    0   0   
P3       2    0   0    
P4       0    0   0     
P5       0    0   0     
P6       0    0   0   
P7       9    0   3
```

I would like to UNPIVOT the months columns, which contain numerical values. This Months column headers are DYNAMIC and will be changing, but the total number of columns will remain the same.

Expected Result

```
---------------------
Region   Month  Qty
---------------------
P1      M07    0
P1      M08    1
P1      M09    0
P2      M07    0
P2      M08    0
P2      M09    0
```

It would be great if I can have some help writing this SQL statement to UNPIVOT and then also consider the dynamic nature of the numerical columns.
It should written in mySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, mysql does not have an `UNPIVOT` function.

Your best option is the `UNION ALL` solution, like :

```
SELECT region, 'M07' AS month, M07 AS qty from stat
UNION ALL
SELECT region, 'M08', M08 AS from stat
UNION ALL 
SELECT region, 'M09', M09 AS from stat
```

It would be possible to create a piece of SQL code (as a stored procedure for example) that would generate this SQL query dynamically by first querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to retrieve the columns names, and using the results to build the query text.

Comment: thanks for your assistance. I have another question. The original data is in an .csv file on my Desktop. I have used your code but I get an error: 

CREATE TABLE stat (
    ID VARCHARACTER(10),
    M07 decimal(4,2),
    M08 decimal(4,2),
    M09 decimal(4,2),
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/blytonpereira/Desktop/Book1.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE book 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;

SELECT region, 'M07' AS month, M07 AS qty from stat
UNION ALL
SELECT region, 'M08', M08 AS from stat
UNION ALL 
SELECT region, 'M09', M09 AS from stat

Comment: @user23456 ... what is your question ?

Comment: pls see comment above. I tried using the code, but I am getting error and not sure why it is happening.

Comment: @user23456, this does not look related to your original question. If you feel that my answer helped you, please accept it, and ask another question if necessary